# Is it mandatory to have a user as "Contact" in office 365 if we want to add user as attendee of the Office 365 calendar event?

Tags: api, rest, office365

Is it mandatory to have a user as "Contact" in office 365 if we want to add user as attendee of the Office 365 calendar event?
At the time of creating event, I am not able to get the list of all the users under my office 365 account active directory (i.e. ad1.com) through any REST api, because of that everytime i have to create contact before creating calendar event with any user.
I am trying to create calendar event using office 365 REST API
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#EventoperationsCreateevents

Answer (score 0):

No, you can add any email address as an attendee. They do not have to be in your Contacts or in your organization at all.